# Android: ProgressDialog not progressing inside a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I'm calling several AsyncTasks to do a job. In order to know when they are done. I have an object (synchronized) with a numerator that holds the number of current running AsyncTasks.

After deploying all of them I do the following:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setProgress(0);
pd.setMax(Utils.getAsyncs());
pd.show();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (Utils.getAsyncs() > 0) 
            pd.setProgress(pd.getMax() - Utils.getAsyncs());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

When the dialog shows, it starts progressing but at some point it gets stuck til the end of everything and then dismisses (as expected).

I tried to put

```
pd.setProgress(pd.getMax() - Utils.getAsyncs());
```

also inside a runOnUiThread but that made things worse and I'm sure I'm missing something else. hence my question. Thanks

edited by request:

```
public static int getAsyncs() {
    return asyncs;
}
```

edit 2: I did the following based on a comment

```
while (Utils.getAsyncs() > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pd.setProgress(pd.getMax() - Utils.getAsyncs());
        }
    });                                    
}
```

and it seems to be better

Comment: We can't do UI operation in other thread. we should run only in UI thread.

Comment: Ofcourse, but adding setProgress to runOnUiThread made things even slower and the progress still got stuck at some point.

Comment: @Amos Why are you calling dismiss on a UI thread ? Just use an another runnable and see what happens.

Comment: pd was created outside the thread so I got an error that I can't dimiss from a thread that didn't create the pd. dismiss() works great, it's the pd.setProgress(pd.getMax() - Utils.getAsyncs()); that doesn't;

Comment: post Utils.getAsyncs()

Comment: The time consuming code is the part that should run in a separate thread, not the ProgressBar, During this the UI thread must be idle and you can use a timer to periodically update the ProgressBar. If the UI thread is busy the ProgressBar will be never updated.

Comment: @quick learner: updated.

Comment: @Tonteria24: the UI thread should be busy only with updating the progressbar, the heavy code is running under another thread.

Comment: @Tonteria24: I updated my question based on your comment. Is that a good direction or maybe I have missed something more basic with handling it?

Comment: Bad direction, sleep freezes the thread and keeps it busy. I added an answer with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class fields

```
private Handler progressHandler = new Handler();
 private Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.setProgress(progressValue);
            progressHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

When the time consuming thread is started

```
// Here start time consuming thread
// Here show the ProgressDialog    
progressHandler.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 1000);
```

When the time consuming thread ends

```
 progressHandler.removeCallbacks(progressRunnable);
 /// Here dismiss the ProgressDialog.
```

**ADDED:**

Instead new Thread(new Runnable) that you probably use for your time consuming code I propose to do this:

To initialize the task :

```
   MyTask task = new MyTask();
   task.execute();
   // Here show the PorgressDialog
   progressHandler.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 1000);
```

Add this private class inside your main class:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        //Here do your time consuming work             
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        // This will be called on the UI thread after doInBackground returns
         progressHandler.removeCallbacks(progressRunnable);
         progressDialog.dismiss();             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand where should I put .removeCallbacks. .postDelayed starts "progressing" (using progressRunnable). Now run() method does its thing until progressValue reaches pd.getMax(). Where does it go when everything finishes?

Comment: call removeCallbacks when thread ends If you want a thread with methods "preExecute" and "postExecute" very handy for show & dismiss dialog then use a thread derived from AsyncTask instead Thread. As many things in Java GC takes care of unused objects.

Comment: so I should call it inside progressRunnable when progrssValue reaches the end? I won't be on the computer so I will be able to check in 1-2 days, sorry about it, I didn't leave this thread.

Comment: I added something more to the answer, I hope will help !

Comment: Actually I followed your previous comments and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do something lik this

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (prStatus < 100) {
                prStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb_2.setProgress(prStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(150);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(prStatus == 100)
                    prStatus = 0;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```